# Pass locals for render partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I render partial like that:

```
<% @assets_new.each do |f| %>

  <li class='asset_item'><%= render f ,:locals => { :main_page => "sample" } %> </li>

<% end %>
```

Then i have _asset.html.erb, for example:

```
<%= main_page %>
```

where i try to read main_page locals but it doesn't work, it throw an error:

```
    undefined local variable or method `main_page' for #
    <#<Class:0x007fe865cc2018>:0x007fe8625cdb98>
```

What i don't understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `:locals`, the correct way to render a partial is:

```
render f, :main_page => "sample"
```

Passing `locals:` is only required when you're using the alternate (old) version of `render`:

```
# Old way
render partial: f, locals: { main_page: 'sample' }

# Or, identical new way
render f, main_page: 'sample'
```

But you cannot mix the two as you've tried to do; in your version, you've created a single "local" called `locals`, with a value of `{main_page: 'sample'}`.

The only time you need the old `render partial:` way is when you're rendering a collection, `render partial: 'user', collection: @users`, and that has also been replaced with a simple `render @users`.